# return does not finish the program in python

Tags: python-3.x, return

Although "if sound_str == None" condition works, the program does not end and keep calling NowYouGotStepSize function. Whats wrong with my return function?

```
def count_horses(sound_str,outputValue=None):
print("sound_str",sound_str)
stepStr = ""
if sound_str == None:
    print("sound_str is =", sound_str)
    return True
for eleman in sound_str:
    if str(eleman) != "0":
        stepStr += "1"works
        NowYouGotStepSize(sound_str,stepStr)
    else:
        stepStr += "0"
```

Thanks

edit: Some of you asked for full code, It did not finished but still may be you can see the mistake.I am trying to solve [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f799eb13e8a260015f58944) kata. Full Code :

```
def NowYouGotStepSize(sound_str,stepStr):
arr=[]
arrStep=[]
outputValue = int(len(stepStr))
for eleman in sound_str:
    arr.append(eleman)
stepStr = stepStr*len(sound_str)
for eleman in stepStr:
    arrStep.append(eleman)
for i in range(0,len(arr)): # horse deleted
    arr[i] = int(arr[i])-int(arrStep[i])
stringWithoutaHorse=""
for eleman in arr:
    stringWithoutaHorse+=str(eleman)
if int(stringWithoutaHorse) == 0: #are there any 1 after delete horse
    return count_horses(None,outputValue) #no means no more horse steps
else:
    return count_horses(stringWithoutaHorse, outputValue) #yes means there are another horse

def count_horses(sound_str,outputValue=None):
    stepStr = ""
    if sound_str == None:
        return "12345"
    for eleman in sound_str:
        if str(eleman) != "0":
            stepStr += "1"
            NowYouGotStepSize(sound_str,stepStr) #horse step size detected
        else:
            stepStr += "0"
```

and input is :
print(count_horses('0212030212')) #output should be [2, 2, 3]

Comment: your indentation is wrong

Comment: `return` will **always** cause a function to exit. Please fix your indentation so it's clear what's a part of the function, and include a [mcve]. You're currently missing code, like `NowYouGotStepSize`.

Comment: Does `print("sound_str is =", sound_str)` execute?

Comment: @Carcigenicate not always, there might be a `finally` to execute :D

Comment: @timgeb It still causes an exit, there will just be some code that executes prior. Unless you have an infinite loop in the `finally`, in which case, Ok, you got me.

Comment: If the program is calling `NowYouGotStepSize()`, then that means `sound_str` was not equal to `None`.  What is the problem?

Comment: I added full code, return "12345" part is only for seeing. It will be outputValue after I solve this problem.